# Skobbler how i can download a custom map?

Tags: ios, iphone, skmaps, offline-mode

I'm using skmaps in a ios app, in this app i have to work offline with cities map and so i have to download the maps the user select. I have implemented the code in the example:

```
#import "MapJSONViewController.h"
#import "MapDownloadViewController.h"
```

The mapJsonViewController is initialized with this block of code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
            NSArray *packages = [appDelegate.skMapsObject packagesForType:SKTPackageTypeContinent];
            MapJSONViewController *mapXMLVC = [[MapJSONViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapJSONViewController" bundle:nil withSKMapPackages:packages];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapXMLVC animated:YES];
```

With :

```
SKTPackageTypeContinent or SKTPackageTypeCity ecc...
```

I'm able to start the controller with the desired hierarchy level of elements but selecting the cities hierarchy i have found that many cities are missing... The documentation is a little bit poor about this detail but, how i can create a download for a city that isn't in that list? Maybe i can create a custom area to download setting some viewport coordinate (that's the best solution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way of "adding" cities/regions to the list is to email the Scout/skobbler team directly and they will create the new map cuts for you (you cannot do it yourself via the SDK, programmatically).